# Angel helping to find a proper wife?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, commentaries, malach-angel, parashat-chaye-sara, eliezer

At one point in time Avraham asks his servant Eliezer to go out and search a wife for his son.

In Bereshit 24:7 Avraham tells him that HaShem will send His messenger (malach) before him.. Eliezer then tells Laban that Avraham told him that HaShem would send His messenger with him and prosper his way (verse 40).

In the rest of the story there is no mention of this messenger. How did Avraham knew of such a messenger, and what did this messenger actually do?

Comment: Did you mean "end" or "send"?

Comment: Please provide the original Psukim you derive your question from.

Comment: Your title is general ("Angel helping to find a proper wife") but your question is about Avrohom ("How did Avraham knew"). Hence the difficulty with tagging it properly. Please fix either.

Answer (score 4):

The Alshich Hakodosh (16th century contempory of Beit Yosef) Asks This very question: Where was the Angel that was supposed to accompany Eliezer? He answers:

> עוד יתכן במאמרם ז"ל כי חמדו להם את כבוד עשרו ויתנו בברותו ראש ליורשו **והמלאך אשר אתו היפך הקערות ואשר בה הסם שם לפני בתואל ועל כן אחרי אכלם לא נזכר כי אם אחיה ואמה וזה יורה ג"כ אומרו ויושם ולא נאמר ויתן** כאומרו ויתן תבן וגו'. וגם אומרו לפניו לאכול לומר לפניו הושם לאכול. אך לזולתו הושם לבלתי אכול כי אם להמית והוא בתואל: ובזה נבא אל הענין והוא כי יתכן כי למה שהמלאך היה בא עמו כמאמר אדוניו ישלח מלאכו לפניך.
>   The Passuk Bereishis 24,33 is written ויישם  but it is said וַיּוּשַׂם which means that when Lavan was "putting" food in front of Eliezezer, really he was poisoning the food to kill Eliezer and take the wealth. **But then came along the Angel that accompanied Eliezer and switched the plates round with Betuel's plate and Betuel got poisoned and died instead of Eliezer who was saved** as stated in Bereishis Rabbah. This is why later in the narrative when Eliezer  asks to take Rivka, that her mother and brother answered because Betuel died from poisoning. And this is why the Angel was sent with him

Answer (score 1):

Here is a beautiful and very detailed answer to your question given by Rabbenu Bachya on Bereshit 24:15

> ויהי הוא טרם כלה לדבר. יש להתבונן בתוספת מלת הוא כי היה הכתוב ראוי לומר ויהי ככלותו לדבר, אבל מלת הוא שמו של הקב"ה, וכן (תהלים ק') הוא עשנו ולא אנחנו, (במדבר י"ח) ועבד הלוי הוא, נרמז בלשון הוא כי היה עמו סיוע אלהים בשליחות ההוא ע"י המלאך שהתפלל עליו אברהם הוא ישלח מלאכו לפניך, ורמז לך הכ' כי המלאך קדם לפניו ועד שלא הספיק לגמור את הדבר כבר היה שם המלאך על עין המים להזמין לו את רבקה, הוא שאמר והנה רבקה יוצאת כי מלת והנה לשון זמון הוא ומיד וירץ העבד לקראתה ממה שראה שעלו המים לקראתה כמו שדרשו רז"ל, ואז התבונן העבד ממה שדבר לו אברהם כי מלאך הש"י עמו. וכן ספר הוא לבני הבית שאמר לו אברהם הוא ישלח מלאכו אתך והצליח דרכך, מפני זה תמצא כי מן העת הזאת שהוברר לו כי המלאך עמו הוא נקרא בפרשה איש. כי עד עתה קראו בשם עבד. וישם העבד. ויקח העבד. וירץ העבד. מכאן ואילך נקרא איש על שם המלאך שהיה עמו שנקרא איש. וכענין שכתוב (דניאל ט) והאיש גבריאל. (בראשית לו) ויאמר האיש נסעו מזה על דעת רז"ל, וע"כ יקראנו על שם המלאך ההולך עמו, והתחיל לומר והאיש משתאה כלומר מתעכב ושוהא בשבילה כי היה מתכוון ומתבונן בענין המלאך שהובטח עליו מתוך שהיה רואה הצלחת המעשים. ומזה יזכירנו הכתוב בשם האיש, ויקח האיש, ויקוד האיש, כה דבר אלי האיש. ויבא האיש הביתה. וכאשר הרשו אותו לבן ובתואל לקחת את רבקה ואמרו הנה רבקה לפניך קח ולך, שהוא גמר השליחות וחתימת הצלחת הדרך חזר העבד לקדמותו, והזכירו הכתוב בלשון עבד כמבראשונה. הוא שאמר ויוצא העבד כלי כסף וכלי זהב. ויקח העבד את רבקה וילך. ותאמר אל העבד. ויאמר העבד. ויספר העבד ליצחק. ואין להקשות מן התלכי עם האיש הזה. כי אינו דברי התורה רק דברי אחיה ואמה, ולא יתכן להם לומר התלכי עם העבד הזה, שאינו דרך מוסר ואין כבודה בכך. ומה שכתוב ותלכנה אחרי האיש והם דברי תורה, זה היה לכבוד רבקה שאין לומר ותלכנה אחרי העבד כי התורה חששה לכבוד רבקה ונערותיה. או אפשר עוד לומר כי האיש משתאה לה רמז למלאך שהיה מתעכב ושוהה על עין המים בשבילה, ומשם ואילך קרא העבד בשם האיש. ומה שיחזק לך הענין הוא אמרו בסוף הפרשה ותלכנה אחרי האיש ויקח העבד את רבקה וילך. באר כי האיש והעבד ענינים חלוקים זה מזה.

Here is a translation of this long comment found on Sefaria.org:

> ויהי הוא טרם כלה לדבר, “and it was before he had finished speaking, etc.” We need to understand the need for the apparently extraneous word הוא in this verse. All the Torah had to write to tell us that Rivkah appeared before Eliezer had completed his prayer was ויהי ככלותו לדברו, “as soon as he had finished speaking, etc.” Actually, the word הוא in this verse is not a personal pronoun, i.e. “he,” but a name of G-d. (compare Genesis 19,33 where we encountered this word in that context) We have numerous examples of the word הוא being a reference to a name of G-d, such as Psalms 100, 3 הוא עשנו ולו אנחנו, “He has made us and we belong to Him;” Numbers 18,23 ועבד הלוי הוא, ”and the Levite will serve G-d, etc.;” the word הוא in that verse means that Eliezer enjoyed G-d’s special assistance in his mission by means of the angel concerning whom Avraham had prayed to G-d that He should make Eliezer’s mission successful (verse 7).The angel, was at hand already before Eliezer had completed praying and he arranged for Rivkah to be the maiden whom Eliezer would address first with his request for water. This is why the Torah wrote: והנה רבקה יוצאת, “and here Rivkah was already in the process of coming out, etc.” The word והנה means that what follows was the result of a special arrangement, invitation. If the servant immediately ran towards her (verse 17) it was because he had noticed the water of the well rising to meet Rivkah on her descent. This is what our sages in Bereshit Rabbah 60,5 have derived from the wording in our verses here. 
>   At that moment Eliezer already understood what Avraham had meant when he had said to him that G-d would send His angel ahead. This is also what he related once he was in Bethuel’s house when he told the family that Avraham had assured him already before he set out on his journey that G-d would send His angel ahead and that he would succeed (verse 40). In view of this it is easy to understand that from the moment that Eliezer had become aware that the angel was supporting him the Torah refers to him no longer as עבד, servant, but as איש, a man of stature. Up until then we read about וישם העבד, “the servant placed;” ויקח העבד, “the servant took;” וירץ העבד, “the servant ran.” From this point on the Torah keeps referring to Eliezer as האיש until he leaves the house of Bethuel with Rivkah. The expressionהאיש is applied to the angel Gavriel in Daniel 9,21. It is also applied to the angel who told Joseph that his brothers had moved away from Shechem, (Genesis 37,17) and that they had been overheard as planning to move to Dothan. In other words, as of the time the angel joined Eliezer in his quest, he himself assumed the role of the angel in an executive manner. 
>   The words והאיש משתאה לה (verse 21) which appear to be somewhat problematical if we assume Eliezer and the angel to have become as one, must be understood as “he was waiting for her;” he did so as he had become aware that his mission was about to be crowned with success. Having done so, the Torah from now on refers to him constantly as האיש, such as when we read (verse 22) ויקח האש, or (verse 26) ויקוד האיש, or (verse 30) כה דבר אלי האיש, etc. When, a little while later, Lavan and Bethuel gave their consent for Eliezer to take Rivkah (verse 51) and they said הנה רבקה לפניך קח ולך, “here Rivkah is in your presence, take her and go,” at which point Eliezer’s mission had been completed, the Torah reverts to describe Eliezer as עבד instead of as האיש. In verse 53 when Eliezer is reported as sharing out gifts, as well as in every subsequent move of his, the Torah speaks of העבד, “the servant,” seeing that the angel’s assistance was no longer required for that part of his activity. Avraham’s prayer which invoked the assistance of an angel had been answered in full. 
>   If you were to ask that when Lavan and his mother asked Rivkah if she were willing to go עם האיש הזה, “with this man,” and this occurred only in verse 58, after verse 51 which we described as the point at which Eliezer’s mission had basically been completed, the answer is simple. The words reported in verse 58 were not spoken by the Torah but by Lavan and his mother. They certainly were not bound by the considerations we described before. How could they be expected to refer to someone as “this slave,” when the person in question was distributing lavish gifts to every member of their household, not to mention to Rivkah herself? Would it not have been a gross insult to their sister to ask her is she were willing to leave her parental home in order to travel to a distant land “with this slave?” 
>   Concerning verse 61 in which both Rivkah and her maids are reported as traveling אחרי האיש, which appears to contradict the explanation I have offered that Eliezer had reverted to being an עבד the moment consent had been obtained for her to become Yitzchak’s bride, this wording was chosen by the Torah in honour of Rivkah. It would not have looked respectful if she had been described as riding “behind the slave.”
>   Another approach to the words והאיש משתאה לה. It is an allusion to the angel who had tarried and waited at the well until the arrival there of Rivkah. From that moment on Eliezer took over the task of the angel; hence he is referred to as האיש from that moment on. Support for this theory is found in the text near the end of the episode where the Torah said (verse 61) “they walked behind האיש, “and the עבד took Rivkah and he went.” This verse makes it crystal clear that the subjects איש and עבד respectively could not have been one and the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer to question from Dr. Itamar Warhaftig of The Bar Ilan University:

> ויאמר אברהם אל עבדו זקן ביתו המֹשל בכל אשר לו שים נא ידך תחת ירכי (כד:ב).
>   מיהו העבד? בכל הפרשה לא נזכר שמו, אך בפרשת לך לך (טו:ב) נאמר:'ובן משק ביתי הוא דמשק אליעזר', ואם כן העבד הוא אליעזר. [1]
>   והנה בסיפור המעשה נקרא אליעזר פעמים בשם עבד ופעמים בשם איש:
>   ויאמר אברהם אל עבדו זקן ביתו המֹשל בכל אשר לו (כד:ב), וכן: שם:ה, ט, י, יז.
>   והאיש משתאה לה מחריש לדעת ההִצליח ה' דרכו (כד:כא), וכן: שם:כב, כו, כט, ל, לב.
>   ויאמר עבד אברהם אנכי (כד:לד), וכן: שם:נב, נג.
>   התלכי עם האיש הזה (כד:נח).
>   וישלחו את רבקה...ואת עבד אברהם (כד:נט).
>   ותקם רבקה ונערֹתיה... ותלכנה אחרי האיש, ויקח העבד את רבקה וילך (כד:סא).
>   ותאמר אל העבד, מי האיש הלזה... ויאמר העבד הוא אדני (כד:סה, סו)
>    מהי משמעות חילופין אלו בכינויו של אליעזר?
>   תחילה יש להציע שני כללים:
>   א)       יש הבדל מהותי בין עבד לאיש. עבד הוא אדם שאינו חופשי, משועבד לאחר, ממלא פקודות ואינו יוזם. ואילו 'איש' הוא לשון חשיבות. [2] אדם חופשי, חושב ויוזם.
>   ב)   יש שהכתוב מכנה אדם בשם זה או אחר מהיבט אובייקטיבי, אך יש שהכינוי מבטא נקודת מבט סובייקטיבית של הדמות המרכזית באותה פרשה. כך ייתכן שהמקרא יכנה אדם 'איש' או 'עבד' על פי האופן שבו רואה אותו הדמות שעליה נסב הסיפור באותו פסוק.
>   לאור כללים אלה נראה לנו להציע כי אליעזר עצמו הוא גם עבד - עבד אברהם, ממלא פקודות אדוניו, אך גם 'איש' - אדם חשוב, חושב ויוזם. תחילה הוא מופיע כ'עבד'; הוא עושה שליחותו ותו לא. אמנם הוא חופשי לבחור את הדרך שבה ימצא את מבוקשו, אבל הוא מוגבל לחפש אישה ממשפחתו של אברהם דווקא ("כי אם אל ארצי", פס' ג), והוא חייב להופיע כעבד אברהם. לכן הפרשה פותחת ב'עבדו', למרות שהוא גם זקן ביתו, המושל בכל אשר לו (פס' ב), והתורה ממשיכה לכנותו 'עבד' (פס' ה, ט, י, יז), גם כאשר הוא יוזם את המבחן. היזמה טפלה לעצם השליחות.
>   המפנה בא בפס' כא, "והאיש [3] משתאה לה, מחריש לדעת". כאן צריך איש שיודע להתבונן ולהתפעל, וגם לפעול על פי התרשמותו. זו אינה תכונה של עבד, לכן כאן בא לידי ביטוי האיש שבו. הוא עובר כביכול למישור אחר. רק "איש" "מחריש לדעת הַהִצליח ה' דרכו אם לא". ובאווירה זו הוא נותן את הצמידים, עוד קודם ששאל מי הנערה, [4] כי הוא חש שעומד הוא בצל ה', ובטוח במבחן שקבע להצלחת שליחותו. בהמשך, מובן שרק על 'איש' ייאמר, "ויקד האיש וישתחו לה'"; שם שמים שגור בפי איש ולא בפי עבד, שיש לו אדון אחר.
>   בפסוקים כט ו-ל, "וירץ לבן אל האיש... כה דבר אלי האיש, ויבא אל האיש", יש סיבה אחרת לכינויו של אליעזר "איש". כאן אליעזר מתואר כפי שהוא נראה בעיני לבן ורבקה. הם רואים אותו כאורח חשוב, אולי קרוב משפחה, שבא מרחוק.
>   אך גם לגופו של עניין רוצה המקרא להדגיש שלבן מתייחס אליו כאיש, ולכן יקשה עליו בעתיד לסרב לבקשתו. יתר על כן, אפשר שמשום כך לא סיפר אליעזר לרבקה מי הוא, כדי שיתייחסו אליו בכבוד, כאיש ולא כעבד. ואכן כך הוא מופיע בפניהם: "ויבֹא האיש הביתה" (פס' לב).
>   אבל כשהוא מתחיל לדבר, שוב בא מפנה: "עבד אברהם אנכי". [5] כלומר, אני חייב לספר לכם את האמת, עבד אני, אבל עבד אברהם, ובאתי כשליח אברהם, וכאילו אברהם עצמו נמצא כאן. וכאשר הסיפור מסתיים בהצלחה – "הנה רבקה לפניך קח ולך" (נא), באה חתימה כעין הפתיחה: "ויהי כאשר שמע עבד אברהם" (נב). מעתה חוזר אליעזר לתפקידו העיקרי כעבד אברהם, ולכן – "ויוצא העבד כלי  כסף" (נג). יתר על כן, כעת הוא נותן ביטוי לכך שגם רבקה היא גבירתו, ולכן הוא מצניע עצמו כעבד. ואולם לבן עדיין מתייחס לאורח כאיש, ושואל את רבקה: "התלכי עם האיש הזה", למרות שהוא יודע שהוא עבד אברהם, אם בגלל המתנות שהביא, ואם בגלל הרושם האדיר שהשאיר עליהם.
>   אמנם בפסוק נט – "וישלחו את רבקה אחֹתם... ואת עבד אברהם" - יש לעיין מדוע כונה כאן עבד, והרי בעיניהם הוא איש? אלא שכאן גובר הכלל שהבאנו כטעם שני בהסברנו לעיל על פסוק נג; כאן רבקה היא גיבורת הסיפור, ההולכת עם מינִקתה, ועם העבד, שעומד להיות גם עבדה. [6] אבל רבקה עצמה מכירה בכוחו של האיש, ובעיניה הוא עדיין איש: "ותלכנה אחרי האיש" (סא). אך בעיני עצמו הוא נתפס כעבד, גם כעבד אברהם וגם כעבד יצחק ורבקה כאמור, ולכן – "ויקח העבד את רבקה" (שם).
>   כשרבקה רואה את יצחק, יצחק הוא האדון, ואליעזר הוא עבד: "ותאמר אל העבד... ויאמר העבד... ויספר העבד" (סה-סו); בנוכחות יצחק חוזר אליעזר להיות עבד.
>   פתחה הפרשה בעבד וסיימה בעבד, ובאמצע תיארה אותו כאיש, לפי הנסיבות.
>   [1] ראה יומא כח, ע"ב: "אליעזר עבד אברהם זקן ויושב בישיבה היה, שנאמר 'ויאמר אברהם אל עבדו זקן ביתו המֹשל בכל אשר לו'. אמר ר' אלעזר שמושל בתורת רבו". וראה תרגום יונתן בן עוזיאל כאן ורש"י לפס' לט.
>   [2]    ראה שמ' א:יא ופירוש דעת מקרא שם. על חשיבותו של אליעזר ראה הערה קודמת.
>   [3]   וכבר עמדו על כך בעלי התוספות על התורה ( תוספות השלם , הוצאת מכון אריאל, בעריכת הרב י' גליס, ירושלים, תשמ"ג) וזה לשונו:"עד השתא קורא לו עבד ועכשיו איש. נ"ל מייד כשהצליח דרכו נתחזק לאיש מלחמה. אבל כשנכנס לבית לבן עשה עצמו עבד מפני כבודו של אברהם".
>   [4]     ראה רש"י שם: "לאחר שנתן לה שאלה, לפי שהיה בטוח בזכותו של אברהם שהצליח הקב"ה דרכו".
>   [5]   הגמרא בבבא קמא צב, ע"ב מביאה לימוד כללי: "מנא הא מילתא דאמרי אינשי מילתא גנאה דאית בך קדים אמרה...דכתיב ויאמר עבד אברהם אנכי".
>   [6]   שמעתי גם פרוש הלכתי האומר כי משמסר האב בתו לשלוחי הבעל היא נחשבת נשואה, ראה כתובות מח, ע"ב, ואם כן אליעזר נהיה גם עבדה של רבקה.

Comment: I'd much appreciate at least a short English summary, as this is an English site.